# Is Glide store downloade image in cache?

Tags: android, android-glide

here my fragment code:

```
Glide.with(context).load(referenceUrl).into(holder.imageViewPhoto);
```

As result **Glide** success download image from remote url. OK. Nice.

1. Download image from remote server
2. Store image in local cache
3. Turn off network and start my Android app
4. Get all images from local cache

I want Glide to automate get image from local cache or (if not exist) from remote URL.

Is it possible with Glide?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you need to use this to download image from url

```
 Glide.with(this)
            .load(url)
            .downloadOnly(500, 500);
```

To load image from local cache, the urls are the same

```
 Glide.with(this)
                .load(url)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(ivAvatar);
```

Comment: I want to delegate this for Glide. Glide must automate to solve is to get image from local cache or from remote url. Is it possible?